I don't understand R_X86_64_64 relocation
This is what the System V ABI specifies:
R_X86_64_64 | S + A (ie Symbol value + Addend)

I assembled this shared object and PIE executable:
; PIE executable

        global _start
        extern msg

        section .text

_start:
        mov rdi, 1      ; stdout fd
        mov rsi, msg
        mov rdx, 9      ; 8 chars + newline
        mov rax, 1      ; write syscall
        syscall

        xor rdi, rdi    ; return code 0
        mov rax, 60     ; exit syscall
        syscall

; shared object
        global msg:data msg.end-msg
        section .data

msg: db "hi there", 10
 .end:

When performing readelf on the PIE executable, in the .rela.dyn I get these relocation entries:
000000001007  000100000001 R_X86_64_64       0000000000003000 msg + 0
000000003000  000100000005 R_X86_64_COPY     0000000000003000 msg + 00

As I understand it:

R_X86_64_64 performs the relocation inside the .text section - it changes the operand (which is located at offset 0x1007 in mem) to the value of the specified symbol (in this case, 0x3000)
R_X86_64_COPY tells the dynamic linker to look for the dynamic symbol in the shared object, and then copy the value of the dynamic symbol to address specified by the symbol (in this case 0x3000) + the base address the object was loaded at

Now if I apply the R_X86_64_64 relocation the way the ABI specified, I will just get 0x3000 as msg's address which is obviously incorrect! Shouldn't I add load base address here too?
Is there something I'm missing?
Thanks in advance

I did not really understand what you mean by adding the base address to the symbol value. You want to somehow reconstruct what things may look like on memory ? The Symbol value (S) is defined by the dynamic linker when relocating your module; so 0x3000 is the offset added to the image's base address to make the new symbol's value when relocating.
Anyway, whenever the dynamic linker finds a R_X86_64_COPY, it copies the object's data into an uninitialized address, belonging to an uninitialized section like .BSS in the main module. Your R_X86_64_64 reference is then relocated by setting it to the uninitialized address within your main module, which has been already initialized by the linker; therefore, your R_X86_64_64 is NOT going to be directly set to the object's address in the other module, but to copied version; it will be set to the absolute address of the copied object.

First off, thanks for the answer.
I didn't phrase myself well, I understood it exactly like you said.
By base address I mean the address the object is loaded into memory (for example the common 0x401000).
Anyway on other relocations when the base address is needed to be added, it is explicitly said so. For example R_X86_64_RELATIVE:
The ABI specifies:
R_X86_64_RELATIVE |  B + A (IE Base address + Addend)

What I find weird is that logically it makes sense to add the base address to R_X86_64_64 too, even though its not specified so

As I pointed out in the answer, the symbol address (S) itself will be the address of the symbol in run-time (The dynamic linker has done the first phase of relocation and each symbol has its unique fixed virtual address on memory); therefore, the base address has already been added, thus it is not required to add the base address again.

What do you mean by "the first phase"? When is this phase done?
From what I understood there is just one phase in which base address is just added when applying the relocation, and unless there is a reason (such as R_X86_64_COPY for example) nothing is deferred for later - there is no reason to.

It is part of the relocation process to assign run-time addresses to symbols and it is done by the dynamic linker when processing the dynamic symbol tables. Just like an static linker, the dynamic linker also has to perform symbol resolution and then relocation. Before fixing the references (Like R_X86_64_64 or R_X86_64_RELATIVE) it first has to assign run-time virtual addresses to the symbols, so that it can fix the references to these symbols correctly.

Hmm I see. But why is there a need to do this in 2 phases? Why not just add the base address when the references are fixed?

See, the dynamic linker/loader has already loaded the shared object before performing the symbol resolution and the relocation for your main module. Your msg symbol in the shared object will have an absolute virtual address. So whenever the linker looks up the symbol table of the shared object, it will see msg's absolute address on memory. Now in your main module, if you reference msg, the linker simply gets the address of msg from the symbol table and the adds the addend to it and saves the sum in the reference's location. That's all it has to do with R_X86_64_64.
